# Where I can get mysql 4.1.3b-beta-nt-max version?

Tags: mysql, version

I need reproduce the exact same environment of a system in production, it's working with mysql **4.1.3b-beta-nt-max** version, where I can get this exact version? I have looking with google but it seems like it's no longer available anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try searching historical databases such as

http://www.oldapps.com/mysql_server.php?old_mysql_server=131

...in a pinch, you can install a "similar" version (such as the one above, 4.1.3beta-win), and then replace the binaries with the production ones. MySQL doesn't do strange things with the registry, so this procedure should suffice.

Comment: you're totally right!, thanks a million.